# Lexicographic Algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

This question may be better suited for Stack Overflow, but I'm partial to this site, so I thought I'd give it a shot:

I'm trying to make an algorithm (potentially even recursive?) that generates a list of the possible outcomes of n bernoulli trials. First ordering the outcomes by the number of success, then ordering those subsets [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). For example, with 2 trials I would like a matrix that looks like this:
$$ \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\1&0\\0&1\\1&1\end{array}\right) $$
Or, for 3,4,5 trials it would look like:
$$ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1\end{array}\right) \ \left(\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0\\1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&1\\1&1&1&0\\1&1&0&1\\1&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{array}\right) \ \left(\begin{array}{ccccc}0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0&1\\0&0&0&1&1\\1&1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&1&0\\1&1&0&0&1\\1&0&1&1&0\\1&0&1&0&1\\1&0&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0&1\\0&1&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&0\\1&1&1&0&1\\1&1&0&1&1\\1&0&1&1&1\\0&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\end{array}\right)$$
This arrangement is important because of the arrangement of other inputs for the R script that I am writing.

EDIT: Something interesting I just noticed: the matrix is symmetric in a way... if you fold after the middle row, a 0 corresponds to a 1 (and vice versa) in the position opposite the fold.

Any thoughts? Right now I'm considering making lexicographic outputs for each set of outcomes that share a number of successes then ammending them? But even then I'm having a hard time producing the lexicographic permuations.

Any thoughts? Or should I move this to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Because this actually isn't a study of bernoulli trials, I just thought it would be easier to word it that way, I can amend them if it's uncomfortable that they aren't there haha

Comment: Your lexicographical ordering seems to be reversed compared to the usual one I think.

Comment: @PeterKošinár, switch the $0$'s and $1$'s... is that the order that you are used to?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=generating+next+lexicographic+combination) what you are looking for?

Comment: @dtldarek that google search wasn't particularly useful... however, the first link would give me a way to reorder a matrix after I had generated all of the values, HOWEVER, I'm not looking for the strict lexicographical order, I'm looking for a two tiered sort, in which the second tier is lexicographical

Comment: @jameselmore [Here](http://www.nebraskaroads.com/csce235/section4_7.html) there is a section titled "Generating the Next Largest r-Combination in Lexicographic Order" (see also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications)). What's wrong with using this for every part (with the same number of positive entries) of your table?

Comment: That would certainly work, after the first 2 results of that google search I was kind of confused as to why you sent it to me

Comment: @jameselmore Well, the links I have sent you were 2nd and 4th results for me ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursion could be like this:
for $w=0,\ldots,n-1$, run through all weight $w$ entries for dimension $n-1$ and output them preceeded with a "0"; run through all weight $w$ entries for dimension $n-1$ again and output them preceeded with a "1".

Comment: This will give the list in lexicographic order.  The OP wants to order the entries first by the number of $1$'s and then, only among entries with the same number of $1$'s, lexicographically.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I do order by weight first, then lexicographic.

Comment: You're right; I read your answer too fast.

Answer (score 2):

To enumerate the outcomes for $k$ successes in $n$ trials in lexicographic order, you can proceed recursively:

1) (if $k \ge 1$) list the outcomes for $k-1$ successes in $n-1$ trials, and prepend $1$ to each.

2) (if $k \le n-1$) list the outcomes for $k$ successes in $n-1$ trials, and prepend $0$ to each.

Comment: What if $1<k<n-1$?

Comment: Then you do both (1) and (2).

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ bits, you will have $1$ word of all zero bits, $n$ words with a single $1$ bit, $n(n-1)/2$ with two $1$ bits, and generally ${n \choose k}$ with $k$ $1$ bits.  For the batch with $k$ $1$ bits, the first ${n-1 \choose k-1}$ will start with $1$ and the remaining ${n-1 \choose k}$ will start with $0$.  This gives a recursive algorithm:
Main
For k=0 to n
For i=0 to ${n \choose k}-1$
Print f(n,k,i)

Function f(n,k,i)# return the $i^{\text{th}}$ of ${n \choose k}$ strings of $n$ bits with $k$ $1$ bits in lexicographic order
If $i \lt {n-1 \choose k-1}$ return $1+$f(n-1,k-1,i)
Else return $0+$f(n-1,k,i-${n-1 \choose k-1}$)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very special case of asking for a lexicographic ordering of n-vectors of integers the sum of which may not exceed a given number k. There is a beautiful closed formula for that, so you really don't need recursion to calculate each vector's rank number (of course, the recursion will be used to prove it). The specialty comes from restricting entries on the coordinates of the vector to a maximum of 1. I don't know if you need the complete table or just the rank numbers. In the latter case, my formula may certainly be of help. If you are still interested, just let me know.